# Floyd's cycle detection algorithm on directed graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

How can Floyd's  cycle detection algorithm  be used to count the length of cycle in directed graph ?
Most of the links that i have come across explains Flyod's cycle algorithm on a linked list but how can the same algorithm be used for directed graphs  ?

Comment: Exactly the same way.

Comment: @if there are edges such as 1>2>3>1 and 4>5>4 leading to two disjoint parts in graph

Comment: Just run it again on some unvisited node (until there is no such node) if you want to detect cycles everywhere (ie if you don't have a starting point, which the algorithm assumes).

Answer (score 0):

When two pointers reach each other, At this point, the pointer a has walked k steps and the pointer b has walked 2k steps, so the length of the cycle divides k. Thus, the first node that belongs to the cycle can be found by moving the pointer a to node x and advancing the pointersstep by step until they meet again.

```
a = x;
while (a != b) {
a = succ(a);
b = succ(b);
}
first = a;
```

After this, the length of the cycle can be calculated as follows:

```
b = succ(a);
length = 1;
while (a != b) {
b = succ(b);
length++;
}
```

reference: "Guide to Competitive Programming: Learning and Improving Algorithms Through Contests
Textbook by Antti Laaksonen"